# How Do I Use Susy 2 $map?

Tags: susy-compass, susy-sass

I have been fairly comfortable with Susy and decided to install susy 2.0.0.rc.1 and sass 3.3.0.rc.4. When I tried to set up $map, exactly as per the Settings documentation, in my _base.scss, liveReload gave me error message after error message with the usual expected after ")" got etc. etc. So I can't even get started. Isn't $map the new way of setting up the grid?

Comment: You can create any number of settings maps in Susy 2, but the default one is actually called `$susy`; I'll make sure that's more clear in the docs. However, that won't cause the error you are seeing. It sounds to me like you are missing a `;` at the end of the map, maybe? Can you paste the full error?

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I tried $susy at the same time as $map and that didn't work either. I've now returned to Susy one or singularitygs and I'll wait until both Susy 2 and Sass 3.3 are finally ready before trying again.

Comment: If you paste more detail, I may actually be able to help. It's hard to know what's going on without being able to see any code.

Comment: Belated thanks, again. In my answer below I've explained what the problem was. I must say that susy 2.1.1 is an excellent tool and the documentation (after a little trial and error) is very thorough.

Answer (score 1):

FYI, LiveReload will not use sass 3.3.0.rc.1 and that is why my $susy won't work. LiveReload uses its own sass. Reverting to compass watch in the Terminal solves the initial problem. So now I know where the problem lies.

I should really delete this question. I found that LiveReload has a plugin for sass 3.3.0 and with a bit of tweaking of folders (in response to LiveReload error message re: compass/gem/compass) I now have it working. So it's possible to compile with LiveReload, CodeKit and Terminal (compass watch).

Now that I can see what's going on, I've returned to susy (now  ver 2.1.1) full time. Singularity has released Version 1.2.0, but the documentation is as limited as before.